remix react route config error - You must provide a non-empty routes array to createStaticHandler
I have made some changes to migrate a project to remix vite. I was running in some challenges related to route configuration under vite.config.ts.  a few challenges I encountered were couldnt find a stable version of vite plugin so ended up using unstable_vitePlugin as remix. Had to use Promise.resolve which I highly doubt is the right thing to do when setting up routes.
Error: I am encountering You must provide a non-empty routes array to createStaticHandler

My vite.config.ts,
import { unstable_vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { remixDevTools } from "remix-development-tools";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

installGlobals();

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
    remixDevTools(),
    remix({
      ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/*.css"],
      routes(defineRoutes) {
        return Promise.resolve(
          defineRoutes((route) => {
            route("/", "root.tsx", { index: true });
            route("about", "routes/about.tsx");
            route("test", "routes/test/index.tsx", () => {
              route("add", "routes/test/add.tsx", { index: true });
              route("delete:testId", "routes/test/delete.$testId.tsx");
              route("edit:testId", "routes/test/edit.$testId.tsx");
            });
          })
        );
      },
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
});

I am not sure what it means by non empty routes array to createStaticHandler. Why does it need an empty array in the first place? Can anyone please provide insights as to how this can be fixed and where does it need an empty array cause I dont seem to have a createStaticHandler function defined. Perhaps the routes are not configured properly in vite.config?

I figured it out. In case anyone needs to do the same.
As per the document link and here, nested routes structuring and naming conventions seems to be wrong. Any files in the routes can be added to a folder / package of its own with the same name.
Excerpt from Docs -

Routes can also be folders with a route.tsx file inside defining the
route module.

Key point:

Note that when you turn a route module into a folder, the route module
becomes folder/route.tsx, all other modules in the folder will not
become routes.

Below examples with or without folders,
- routes/
  - example.tsx
  - example.add.tsx
  - example.edit.$id.tsx
  - example.delete.$id.tsx

is exactly the same as,
- routes/
 - example/
  - route.tsx
  - add.tsx
  - edit.$id.tsx
  - delete.$id.tsx

Notice the change of example.tsx file name to route.tsx while containing the same code.
Changes made,
import { unstable_vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { remixDevTools } from "remix-development-tools";
import { installGlobals } from "@remix-run/node";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

installGlobals();

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
  plugins: [
    remixDevTools(),
    remix({
      ignoredRouteFiles: ["**/*.css"],
      routes(defineRoutes) {
        return Promise.resolve(
          defineRoutes((route) => {
route("/", "routes/_index/route.tsx", { index: true });
            route("/about", "routes/about/route.tsx");
            route("/test", "routes/test/route.tsx", { index: true });
            route("/add", "routes/test/add.tsx");
            route("/delete:testId", "routes/test/delete.$testId.tsx");
            route("/edit:testId", "routes/test/edit.$testId.tsx");
          })
        );
      },
    }),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
});

One of the things I was not able to figure out was why do the routes for add, edit and delete doesnt work. Documentation clearly explains that they need to be either in there separate folders or I need to use a different route strategy to make this work.
